# Looking for a layman's plasma simulator

Tags: physics, software-recommendations, virtual-reality

Modelling plasma in a magnetic field is hard, it has to be or we would have fusion power already.

**Do you know of an application that could be used to simulate the rough / dumbed-down behaviour of a non-dissipating plasma within magnetic fields, which can be moved / manipulated by the user?**

I want to experiment with what setup of magnetics field i would have to operate to bring plasma into a certain form / motion.

Ideally the app would be freeware or pretty cheap as I will use it for hobby purposes.

*Explanation after Comments:*

I want to write about plasma within a magnetic field. I am looking for a way to help me visualise and conceptualize how the plasma would look and how magnetic fields in different positions would move and form the plasma. Something like a particle simulator for plasma I guess.

With 'Non-dissipating' I meant the plasma in the simulation is permanent and does not dissipate as plasma will do in an athmosphere, right?

Comment: That is not how science works. We don't have fusion batteries in our cells phones for the same reason that we don't have anti-matter generators - the science is much ahead of the engineering involved. If you don't understand magnetic fields you will get as much out of any simulator as someone who hates rocket science would get from an orbital mechanics simulator.

Comment: This isn't a world building question (a question about the rules and systems of a fictional world) or even asked for the purposed of developing those rules and systems.  VTC:NAB.  Have you asked over at [physics.se]?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1851/

Comment: (FWIW, I'd consider voting to close, but requests for resources and simulators have been allowed in the past, so I'll leave this one open. I doubt you'll get any useable answers, though)

Comment: *"Behaviour of a non-dissipating plasma within magnetic fields":* what does this even mean? Google finds only of 5 (five) results for the phrase "non-dissipating plasma", of which one is this question.

Comment: I updated the questions with explanations.

Comment: @Renan I follow the fusion power news. They currently do struggle to simulate the plasma 100% correct and to find a way to contain it for longer periods of time, right? That's what I meant.

Comment: Plasma physics is a wide field, so what kind of simulation software you need really depends on the characteristics of the plasma you're looking at and what regimes and environments it's in. Without knowing things like the debye length, ion species, magnetic field strength, and temperature it's impossible to give a good answer. And unfortunately, if you didn't understand some of those words I doubt even applicable software would be useful to you-- almost all plasma physics simulation software I know of requires at least a basic knowledge of plasma physics.

Comment: @elduderino Thats why I am asking here. Everything I found was really scientific :)

Comment: Look for Teaching Physics Software.

Comment: *Everything I found was really scientific*  You are asking for *simulation* software, and by definition that's going to be *very, very* scientific.  What I suspect you really need is more like the book equivalent of "Plasma for Dummies" and I doubt that exists.  You might try YouTube for introductory videos on plasma physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want a layman’s tool — implying no knowledge or limited knowledge about plasma physics and the mathematics required to perform simulations

You might consider the [Remote Glow Discharge Experiment](https://scied-web.pppl.gov/rgdx/#) which allows you to control a plasma source via your web browser.

If you have the willingness to learn then there are many tools and frameworks that can be used to simulate plasmas in different regimes — low pressure, atmospheric and stellar

The folks at Eindhoven University have a good toolset for [low pressure systems](https://plasimo.phys.tue.nl/applications/index.php)

And NASA and Los Alamos have many more, but these are all targeting college students and researchers in the field.

There are commercial products with free trial licenses like COMSOL that will likely have example environments for different plasma applications.  But, understanding them and manipulating them require an understanding of the underlying physics, computational fluid dynamics, and Particle in a cell (PIC) simulation.